# How to preventDefault inside method

Tags: javascript, events, preventdefault

When executing submit, "e" is undefined... How to `preventDefault` and then `execute()`?
I've tried "`this.execute`" (without brackets), but then the variable "form" is not accessible.
Also tried this:

```
this.form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){e.preventDefault(); this.execute();}, false);
```

but not working.

```
class Filters {
    form;

    constructor(form) {
        this.form = form;
        this.form.addEventListener("submit", this.execute(), false);
    }

    execute(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        [...]
    }
}

let f = new Filters([...],[...]);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You are not passing any parameters to `execute` function

Comment: Change `this.execute()` to `this.execute.bind(this)`

Comment: I get ```e is undefined```

Comment: You are calling the function, not passing it as reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the event to your execute method as a parameter like shown below.

```js
class Filters {
    form;

    constructor(form) {
        this.form = form;
        // Either use an arrow function or this.execute.bind(this) 
        this.form.addEventListener("submit", e => this.execute(e), false);
    }

    execute(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        [...]
    }
}
```